# How to use API Level 17 methods in app and complie the code for Ginger Bread?

Tags: android

I am new to android. I've downloaded ADT and it has come with Jelly Bean ( API Level 17 ) SDK.

I have set the target sdk to be "9" in the AndroidManifest.xml.

I am able to use latest API level 17 methods and it runs great on android JB simulator.

But after making the build, if I try to install it in my real ginger bread device, the simplest app won't run and crash.

Can anyone suggest me a solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the SDK for Gingerbread (API level 9, Android 2.3) and compile your code with that. You will get compile-time errors where you are using methods that don't exist in Gingerbread. You will then need to decide what to do about that. You can either

1. remove those method calls and use other/similar ones that are available in 2.3 OR
2. use the backwards-compatibility library (if it exists)

Comment: Can you provide any link for any backward compatibility libraries ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml and look for the  tag.  Even if your app is targeted for API 17, devices with earlier API versions, you can continue to support them by specifying a minimum API version attribute.

Example:

```
<!-- minimum API version is 8 = GingerBread_MR -->

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Comment: minSdkVersion is set to 8 and I tried all the targetSdkVersion from 9 to 17. But the app doesn't run on my real ginger bread 2.3.6 device.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html. Did you add support library?

Comment: Then do what David Wasser suggested.  I assumed that you grabbed all of the APIs and images available, which was a bad assumption on my part.  Go to Eclipse > Window Menu > Android SDK Manager and make sure you have every last thing available either already installed or checked off for download.  Get it all.  And looking at your post, I see that I'm way past my bedtime, having missed a critical piece of information. :P

Comment: Setting minSDK will not prevent the compiler from letting you compile the app using APIs that don't exist on those devices. You need to know which APIs are available on the devices you want to support and you need to ensure that you don't try to use unsupported or unavailable APIs (there are different ways of doing this). Setting minSDK only prevents the app from being **installed on devices that have an API level lower than minSDK**